# Possible bug with dependency injection on MvvmCross

Tags: c#, singleton, xamarin, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I'm currently working on a cross platform (Android and iOS) using the brilliant MVVMCross and things are going pretty great with the application and no major hassles so far.

However today I've hit one that's causing me some problems. I'm a strong believer in separation of concerns and what I'm trying to do is to register a class as a lazy singleton implementer of two different interfaces. This is my App.cs in the PCL:

```
public class App : Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        RegisterAppStart<LoginViewModel>();

        Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser, SystemConfigProvider>();
        Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISystemConfigProvider, SystemConfigProvider>();
    }
}
```

The `ISystemConfigProvider` will have a number of readonly properties only and will be injected into viewmodels that need to read the system config.

The `ISystemConfigProviderInitializer` will be injected into the DataService (itself constructed by IoC) and has an Initialize() method that allows a poco to be passed in which sets all the properties mentioned for the `ISystemConfigProvider`

For completeness `SystemConfigProvider` is like this:

```
public class SystemConfigProvider: ISystemConfigProvider, ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser
{
   public string Name {get;}
   ....
   public string Z {get;}

   public void Initialize(PocoObjToSetPropertiesAbove obj)
   {
      //set all properties
   }

}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `SystemConfigProvider` class is getting created multiple times. twice, seemingly once per each interface which contradicts what I'm told by the MVVMCross wiki page about Service Location and Inversion of Control:

> Technical Note> the lazy singleton implementation here is quite technical - it ensures that if a >class implements IOne and ITwo then the same instance will be returned when resolving both IOne >and ITwo.

If I do away with the `ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser` interface and lump the Initialize() into the `ISystemConfigProvider` and only LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton the `ISystemConfigProvider` interface then all works fine as far as I can see but it then means that all consumers of `ISystemConfigProvider` can now see an Initialize() method that they shouldn't see.

I'd greatly appreciate some advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the Mvx IoC container treats the *singleton* aspect at the interface level, not the instantiated type. So it doesn't see that `SystemConfigProvider` is the same type and should only create one instance.

To work around this problem, there are a couple of options:

1) Simply instantiate the singleton at initialization time, then register that singleton for each interface:

```c#
var provider = Mvx.IocConstruct(SystemConfigProvider);
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser>(provider);
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISystemConfigProvider>(provider);
```

2) Pass a builder *Func* to the registration

```c#
Mvx.RegisterSingleton(() =>
{
    var provider = Mvx.IocConstruct<ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser>();
    return provider;
});

Mvx.RegisterSingleton(() =>
{
    var provider = Mvx.Resolve<ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser>();
    if (provider == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ISystemConfigProviderInitialiser should be resolved first.");
    }
    return (ISystemConfigProvider)provider;
});
```

I'm assuming that the *Initialiser* should be resolved first, since there is an explicit *Initialise()* step, so I throw an exception if it is null.

I think Option #1 is probably better. It's simple and explicit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is also some help available from `RegisterAsLazySingleton ` - see the use of `MvxLazySingletonCreator ` in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxTypeExtensions.cs#L189 - so I think you could do `(new Type [] {typeof(SystemConfigProvider)}).AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazSingleton()` - or we could add a pull that didn't use `IEnmerable` quite so heavily.

Comment: @slodge Thanks guys, I've just decided to with the Option 1 above and instantiate it myself and then register that instance for both interfaces. Simplest and easiest solution to move on with this app.